# Prove that using mean value theorem

Tags: analysis

Let $a>b>0$ and let $n$ be an integer greater than or equal to $2$. Prove that $a^{1/n} − b^{1/n} < (a − b)^{1/n}$.
Hint: Let $f(x) = x^{1/n} − (x − 1)^{1/n}$ on the interval $[1, \frac{a}{b} ]$ and use the mean value theorem.

My working:
Using the hint given, since f is differentiable on $[1,\frac{a}{b}]$,
i will take $\frac{f(\frac{a}{b})-f(1)}{\frac{a}{b}-1}$, then i have difficulty halfway through..

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: To link the inequality you want to prove with $f$, I suggest you factorize by $b^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{n}} − (x − 1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ on the interval $[1, \frac{a}{b} ]$

Differentiate $f'(x)=\frac{1}{n}x^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)} − \frac{1}{n}(x − 1)^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)}=\frac{1}{n}(x^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)}-(x − 1)^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)})$.

It is easy to see that $\frac{1}{n}-1 <0$ and $0\leq x − 1< x$. So
$x^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)}<(x − 1)^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)}.$

Thus $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [1, \frac{a}{b}].$

- Use the mean value theorem:

Since f is continuous and differentiable on $[1, \frac{a}{b}]$, there exists a point $c \in [1, \frac{a}{b}]$ such that $\frac{f(\frac{a}{b})-f(1)}{\frac{a}{b}-1}= f'(c)$. Because $f'(x) <0$ for all $x \in [1, \frac{a}{b}].$ Thus $f'(c)<0$. It follows that $\frac{f(\frac{a}{b})-f(1)}{\frac{a}{b}-1}<0$ or $f(\frac{a}{b})-f(1)<0.$

Since $f(1)> f(\frac{a}{b}) \Leftrightarrow 1> {(\frac{a}{b})}^{\frac{1}{n}} − (\frac{a}{b} − 1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Leftrightarrow  1> {(\frac{a}{b})}^{\frac{1}{n}} − (\frac{a-b}{b})^{\frac{1}{n}}\Leftrightarrow a^{\frac{1}{n}} − b^{\frac{1}{n}} < (a − b)^{\frac{1}{n}}$